# How import json.org library to Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I have import json.org library to Android Studio. I go to File > Project Structure, and there must be [image]

but i have [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to import jar file as a module while working on ANDROID studio. Just put the library anywhere in your project folder and then add the reference to your project as a jar file.

```
1. Hit f4 in android studio and open your project structure.

2. By clicking on "module pane" select your "project"

3. Once that is done click on the dependencies tab

4. Click the green + sign and navigate to where you put your parse jar file.

5. Once located you click apply and ok

6. Happy Parse
```